# Apache: How to restrict access to a folder by whitelisting IP addresses?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to limit access to one subdirectory from only two specific IP addresses. I have tried

```
Require ip <my ip>
```

and

```
Order allow,deny
allow from <my ip>
```

and

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from MyIP
```

Tried again

```
<RequireAny>
Require ip <my ip>
Require ip <my ip>
</RequireAny>
```

After adding any of those restrictions into my htaccesss I am getting Forbidden error. How can I allow access only from my two IPs?

my vhost has these lines, do you think I did any mistake here?

```
<Directory /home/mysite/>
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure you are using one of the following  directives only ,not the both at the same time across all the conf files of apache:
either :

```
   Require all denied
   Require ip 14.14.14.14 50.50.50.50
```

or

```
    Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 14.14.14.14, 50.50.50.50
```

if you mix them you'll get 403  (you use one across all configuration files ).

Also , check your ip , make sur you are not using a NAT solution or using a reverse proxy.
you can see you ip in your access_log if you have configured them

Comment: Yes, I did not mix, I tested one by one. Your provided code also give the same forbidden error for any IP including whitelisted.

Comment: can you verrify that your apache user have read access to your files.

Comment: Yes I have www-data:www-data permission

Comment: i am talking about the read permission , you can view it by tiping `ls -ld  /home/mysite` for the folder permessions 
and then `ls -l  /home/mysite` for the files in it.